# Raise a Flash event from Javascript button click

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have a few buttons on my JS page. On click of those, I need to raise events in a flash swf below the buttons that will call popups in it. What can I do for this?

Comment: I essentially need to raise Flash events from javascript. I'll then add event listeners in flash for those events and do the necessary tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want [ExternalInterface.addCallBack()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29).

Documentation & example here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ca7

Comment: But this is just a callback to one function right? What If I want to raise an event? I can then choose to add as many subscribers to the event as I want

Comment: Yeah but `raising an event` in Actionscript 3 is basically calling a function. So why don't you raise that event in callback function and you're done. You can't subscribe to Javascript events from Actionscript anyway.